# Java value object comparison methods

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and trying to learn.

Java doesn't have operator overloading, so when coding a value object I understand that you need to compare objects with an overridden 'equals' method instead of the == operator, but I have yet to read about the other methods you need to override. What about the equivalent methods for the other common operators: >, <, >=, and <=. Do these methods need to be overridden, or do I have to create them if I need them. If I have to create these methods, there must be some standard naming convention for them ('gt', 'lt', 'gte', 'lte'). What is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into the [`Comparable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

Comment: so >= would be: (obj1.compareTo(obj2) > -1)? Are there also interfaces for value objects that need to perform arithmetic operations (Addable, Multipliable, etc)?

Comment: @limscoder I'm afraid there's no such interfaces. You implement `comparable` to compare the equality. What would you need those interfaces for?

Comment: @doctrey I can give many examples of overloading operator arithmetic  in Python (my current language of choice): Dates, Decimals (fixed precision number objects), ORM operations (orm.update(obj.attr + 5), etc. For a Java example, the first half of Kent Beck's TDD book covers developing a 'Currency' value object. Certainly, you'd want the ability to perform arithmetic on your currency objects, so if there isn't an explicit interface, there must be a standard naming convention, 'add' for +, 'times' for *, etc.

Comment: You can simply add methods such as add(), multiply(), etc...  If you want to use operator overloading I'm afraid you will need to use a different language.  Personally I wish they would add it to Java as well.

Comment: for the >=, I would use obj1.compareTo(obj2) >= 0 instead of > -1, just for greater clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override `hashCode()` (used by all hash collections) and `equals()`. It's a rule that if `a.equals(b)`,  `a.hashCode()` should equal `b.hashCode()`.

For comparisons you may implement the interface `Comparable`. For this interface you'll need to implement a `compareTo` method which is an equivalent of <, =, > (note that `a.compareTo(b) == 0` does NOT imply or require that `a.equals(b)`!). Implementing `Comparable` is optional and only useful if you're interested in sorting or certain order-based collections such as `TreeSet`.

Comment: Yes. you can also implement `comparator` to compare every two object of the same type for equality.

Answer (score 0):

In java, the [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface is meant exactly for that. For a "canonical example", have a look into the the `java.lang.Integer` class and see the implementation of `equals()`, `hashCode()` and `compareTo()`. Also, have a look at the JavaDoc info available for these methods in `java.lang.Object` and `java.lang.Comparable`.